# I execute the application on Android emulator it works fine but when I export to APK and I test it on my mobile it does not work

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-emulator

When I execute the application on Android emulator it works fine but when I export to APK and I test it on my mobile it does not work error message "unfortunately. ArduinoBlinkLED has stop". I don't know why! How can I figure out the problem on my mobile?

Mobile information:

Mobile Manufacturer => Motorola RAZR and 
Android version  =>  4.0.4

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yoursite.arduinoblinkled" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".ArduinoBlinkLEDActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory"></uses-library>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is logcat results (errors):

```
11-09 21:06:13.428: E/Netd(33): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
11-09 21:06:13.428: E/Netd(33): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
11-09 21:06:22.347: E/PhonePolicy(37): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
11-09 21:06:47.098: E/BatteryService(93): usbOnlinePath not found
11-09 21:06:47.098: E/BatteryService(93): batteryVoltagePath not found
11-09 21:06:47.107: E/BatteryService(93): batteryTemperaturePath not found
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93):   at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93):   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.readUserList(UserManager.java:114)
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:81)
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:85)
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:923)
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
11-09 21:06:48.807: E/StrictMode(93):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
11-09 21:06:58.867: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
11-09 21:06:58.867: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
11-09 21:06:59.077: E/EventHub(93): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
11-09 21:06:59.077: E/EventHub(93): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
11-09 21:06:59.487: E/CommandListener(33): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
11-09 21:06:59.487: E/WifiStateMachine(93): Failed to disable IPv6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate to native daemon for disabling ipv6
11-09 21:06:59.587: E/MobileDataStateTracker(93): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
11-09 21:06:59.587: E/MobileDataStateTracker(93): default: Could not enable APN type "default"
11-09 21:07:10.258: E/ActivityThread(159): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
11-09 21:07:10.268: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(159): Could not find a dictionary pack
11-09 21:07:24.417: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-09 21:07:24.427: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-09 21:07:24.437: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-09 21:07:24.487: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-09 21:07:24.497: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-09 21:07:24.547: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-09 21:07:24.707: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-09 21:07:24.767: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-09 21:07:24.827: E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93): Load: 6.0 / 1.65 / 0.56
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93): CPU usage from 0ms to 23052ms later:
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   30% 93/system_server: 22% user + 8.1% kernel / faults: 4812 minor 3 major
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   9.7% 145/com.android.systemui: 6% user + 3.6% kernel / faults: 3104 minor 3 major
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   9.6% 190/com.android.launcher: 5.6% user + 3.9% kernel / faults: 2512 minor 6 major
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   6.7% 247/android.process.acore: 5% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 794 minor 1 major
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   5.8% 178/com.android.phone: 4% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 881 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   5.1% 269/app_process: 4.6% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 2107 minor 1 major
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   4.9% 36/surfaceflinger: 1.8% user + 3% kernel / faults: 2 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   3.3% 274/com.android.contacts: 2.2% user + 1% kernel / faults: 2467 minor 16 major
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   2.4% 205/com.google.process.gapps: 1.8% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 450 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   1.6% 37/zygote: 1.5% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 239 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   1.4% 45/adbd: 0.1% user + 1.3% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   1% 159/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0.5% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 336 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   0.3% 35/rild: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   0.1% 30/servicemanager: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   0% 31/vold: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   0.1% 92/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   0% 28/mmcqd: 0% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):  +0% 295/fsck_msdos: 0% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):  +0% 328/com.android.defcontainer: 0% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93): 100% TOTAL: 67% user + 32% kernel + 0.2% softirq
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93): CPU usage from 19702ms to 21344ms later:
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   24% 93/system_server: 15% user + 9% kernel / faults: 347 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     13% 108/ActivityManager: 7.8% user + 6% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     7.2% 314/Error dump: sys: 5.4% user + 1.8% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     3% 100/Compiler: 2.4% user + 0.6% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.8% 243/Binder Thread #: 1.2% user + 0.6% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.2% 93/system_server: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.2% 105/Binder Thread #: 0.6% user + 0.6% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.2% 172/Binder Thread #: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.2% 222/Binder Thread #: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.2% 244/Binder Thread #: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.6% 104/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.6% 107/er.ServerThread: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.6% 111/PackageManager: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.6% 240/Binder Thread #: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.6% 245/Binder Thread #: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.6% 246/Binder Thread #: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.6% 337/Error dump: sys: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   21% 247/android.process.acore: 18% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 127 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     14% 262/Binder Thread #: 14% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     6.9% 249/GC: 5.9% user + 1% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1% 254/Compiler: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   12% 178/com.android.phone: 8.5% user + 3.9% kernel / faults: 102 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     11% 178/m.android.phone: 8.5% user + 3.4% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     2.8% 186/Compiler: 1.7% user + 1.1% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.1% 242/RILReceiver: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.5% 233/RILSender: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   10% 145/com.android.systemui: 6.9% user + 3.4% kernel / faults: 78 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     9.2% 145/ndroid.systemui: 5.7% user + 3.4% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.7% 152/Compiler: 1.1% user + 0.5% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.5% 157/Binder Thread #: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   10% 190/com.android.launcher: 4.7% user + 5.9% kernel / faults: 18 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     9.4% 190/ndroid.launcher: 4.1% user + 5.3% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   1.9% 36/surfaceflinger: 0.4% user + 1.4% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.9% 36/surfaceflinger: 0.9% user + 0.9% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     1.4% 64/SurfaceFlinger: 0.4% user + 0.9% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.4% 66/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   0.9% 35/rild: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.9% 61/rild: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   1.2% 45/adbd: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.6% 45/adbd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):   0.5% 328/com.android.defcontainer: 0% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 3 minor
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93):     0.5% 341/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
11-09 21:07:47.342: E/ActivityManager(93): 100% TOTAL: 60% user + 39% kernel
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93): problem reading network stats
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:300)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:743)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$8.handleMessage(NetworkStatsService.java:1633)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     ... 9 more
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
11-09 21:07:55.601: A/NetworkStats(93):     ... 11 more
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93): problem reading network stats
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:300)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:743)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$1.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:612)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     ... 11 more
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
11-09 21:07:57.801: A/NetworkStats(93):     ... 13 more
11-09 21:08:01.461: E/ActivityThread(380): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
11-09 21:08:01.501: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(380): Could not find a dictionary pack
11-09 21:08:05.551: E/DefaultVoicemailNotifier(274): No voicemails to notify about: clear the notification.
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat errors. Otherwise we won't be able to help you, since we don't know why either...

Comment: Do you have proguard enabled?

Comment: I am a total newbie to all this android development . I will check proguard . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the logcat results, it's almost impossible to give the most accurate diagnostics. but here's a stab in the dark if you're not willing/able to post the logcat

I think it's the fact that your device is probably an android 2.3.3 and doesn't support certain USB features, refer to:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

and try on a different phone, and specify exactly what you need

Also, using eclipse, refresh, clean project and rebuild & run. (always good practice for weird bugs)

Comment: I think David is right.  USB communication is something that was recently added, and therefore won't be available on your older device.